# Regexp to match domain and subdomains (in Java)

Tags: java, regex, url

I need to verify if given URL matches my domain mask.

Example: I want to allow only domains which satisfy this "pseudo-mask":

```
https://*.domain.com
http://*.domain.com
```

So next domains are OKAY:

```
http://my.domain.com/something/blah.html
https://www.domain.com/
http://domain.com/go/somewhere.html
https://very.weird.domain.com/index.jsp
```

but next domains are NOT OKAY:

```
https://domain.com.google.com/other.html
http://my.domainfake.com/haha.jsp
https://my.fakedomain.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^https?://[^/@]*\.domain\.com(/.*)?$
```

(The not-`/` to stop `.domain.com` appearing in the path, the not-`@` to stop username:password@ abuse.)

Better, though: use the [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class built into Java to parse a URL properly. You can then just read the [`host`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getHost%28%29) property and check that it `endsWith` your domain.

Comment: The original ‘pseudo-mask’ pattern doesn't either. :-) Naturally you can throw a `([^/@]*\.)?` group around the front bit if that's what you want. With `URL` you would have to check for `url.getHost().equals("domain.com") || url.getHost().endsWith(".domain.com")`​.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`^https?://(?:[^./@]+\.)*domain\.com(?![^/])`

`[^.]+\.` means *one or more non-dot characters, followed by a dot*; a quick and dirty way to match a domain-name component and its trailing dot.  I wouldn't use that to *find* domain names in a larger body of text, but it's good enough for the kind of validating you're doing.  Put that in a group and add the `*` quantifier to get a regex that matches zero or more components.

You don't really care what comes after the domain name, but you do have to make sure you've reached the end of it; for example, you don't want to match `http://domain.company.com`.  The final part of the regex, `(?![^/])`, is a negative lookahead that means *if there is another character after this, and that character is not `/`, fail*.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
"http://a.domain.com".indexOf("domain.com")
```

this will return -1 if the requested string is not in the text.

since you can don't want '.' after 'domain.com'

you can can use

```
"http://a.domain.com".indexOf("domain.com.")
```

and check whether it is -1 or not

Comment: very bad practice, since this will match for evildomain.com