# How do I return the subdomain from a URL using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, string

I thought this would be something simple to do with regular expressions but so far the solution is proving to be elusive. Here is the scenario - I want to capture the subdomain portion of a URL but not "www." if it exists, e.g. assuming either of these URLs

> www.mysubdomain.mydomain.com
>   mysubdomain.mydomain.com

I want the expression to return only **mysubdomain** - no dots!

Comment: Lots of answer for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189128/regex-to-extract-subdomain-from-url or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093806/regexp-to-match-domain-and-subdomains-in-java

Comment: and if there are subdomains of subdomains? And what about something like `subdomain.domain.co.uk`?

Comment: @Beat I don't care about the second situation - this is for a specific .com domain. As for subdomains of subdomains - correct me if I'm wrong but isn't that what "www" is in the first example? Anyway, "www" is the only use case of subdomain of subdomain I am interested in, and I only want to strip it out.

Comment: @sk8terboi87ツ Neither of those answer my question. Each is trying to solve a slightly different problem. The first one comes close but includes "www.".

Comment: Does the string go through any validation before the extraction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the language you use support lookbehind you can use this:

```
(?<=^www\.|^)[^.]+
```

If it doesn't, use this:

```
^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)
```

and your result is in the first capturing group, example in javascript:

```
var mystring = 'www.mysubdomain.mydomain.com';
var match = /^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)/.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried both of those in two different online Regex testers [RegEx Pal](http://regexpal.com/) and [JRX](http://www.cuneytyilmaz.com/prog/jrx/jrx.nongecko.html) and the first syntax doesn't work at all, the second doesn't do what I want - it also returns the "www.".

Comment: @user2479894: normal for the first pattern, javascript doesn't have the lookbehind feature. The second pattern returns `www.subdomain`, normal too, but you can extract from your result the first capturing group that contains only `subdomain`